# How can override the view files of the componenet in joomla

Tags: view, joomla, overriding, joomla-component

I using the [ARI Quiz lite](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/extension/living/education-a-culture/ari-quiz-lite) for online quiz. i need to orverride view of quiz listing, but i dont know how to do this. I tried to override listing file

```
 /components/com_ariquizlite/view/quiz_list.html.php
```

to

```
/templates/rhuk_milkyway/html/com_ariquizlite/view/quiz_list.html.php
```

but it's not working. please help me. thx adv....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try dropping the /view/ from your second file path - it shouldn't be needed.

There's more guidance here: https://docs.joomla.org/Understanding_Output_Overrides but in Joomla 3 you can do this in the back-end, guessing using Milkyway you're still on 1.5 though :(

Comment: It might be that they don't support template overrides - try asking on their forum: http://www.ari-soft.com/ARI-Quiz-Lite/